# Encontrar arquivo na mesma pasta em codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Como faço para passar a URL em javascript para encontar o arquivo em codeigniter, no PHP eu passo `"<?php echo base_url()?>"` essa variavel para encontrar arqiuvos CSS/JS/IMAGENS, agora essa variavel não funciona no javascript, estou usando codeigniter.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#rua").keyup(function() {
    //Recuperar o valor do campo
    var rua = $(this).val();
    //Verificar se hรก algo digitado
    if (rua != '') {
      var dados = {
        pesq_rua: rua,
        pesq_cidade: document.getElementById('cidade').value,
        pesq_uf: document.getElementById('uf').value
      }
      //Uso codeigniter, como devo fazer para encontrar
      //este arquivo "pesquisacep.php" na mespa pasta que esta o cadastro de cliente
      //Para arquivos CSS,JS, Imagens uso esse codigo para encontar "<?php echo base_url()?>"
      //Mas em java não encontra
      $.post('pesquisacep.php', dados, function(retorna) {
        //Mostra dentro da ul os resultado obtidos 
        $(".resultado").html(retorna);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>ViaCEP Webservice</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!-- Adicionando JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="POST" id="form-pesquisa" action="">
    <label>Estado:
 <select id="uf" name="uf">
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
  <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
  <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
  <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
  <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
  <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
  <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
  <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
  <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
  <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
  <option value="MG" selected>Minas Gerais</option>
  <option value="PA">Pará</option>
  <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
  <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
  <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
  <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
  <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
  <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
  <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
  <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
  <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
  <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
  <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
  <option value="EX">Estrangeiro</option>
 </select>
</label>
    <label>Cidade:
 <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" placeholder="Digite o nome da cidade"></label>
    <label>Rua:
 <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua"  placeholder="Digite o nome da rua"></label>

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="resultado">

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma variável chamada url, e atribuir o endereço a ela, e depois inserir a variável no lugar do 'pesquisacep.php'. Vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#rua").keyup(function() {
        //Recuperar o valor do campo
        var rua = $(this).val();
        //Verificar se hรก algo digitado
        if (rua != '') {
          var dados = {
            pesq_rua: rua,
            pesq_cidade: document.getElementById('cidade').value,
            pesq_uf: document.getElementById('uf').value
          }
          //CRIANDO VARIÁVEL PARA RECEBER A URL
          var url = "<?php echo base_url('caminho_do_arquivo/pesquisacep.php'); ?>";

          //Mas em java não encontra (Só um detalhe caso vc não tenha apenas abreviado o nome... Javascript não é java)

          //EM VEZ DE COLOCAR O NOME DO ARQUIVO AQUI APÓS O POST, USE O NOME DA VARIÁVEL COM O ENDEREÇO
          $.post(url, dados, function(retorna) {
            //Mostra dentro da ul os resultado obtidos 
            $(".resultado").html(retorna);
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

Essa não é uma maneira viável de fazer isso, o ideal seria vc usar esse arquivo "PESQUISACEP.PHP", como uma biblioteca (Library), e daí criar uma função em um controller pra chamar ela, e só então usar o base_url() pra chamar essa função no controller em que vc criar a função. Tenta fazer dessa maneira que mostrei pra você, caso não esteja satisfeito, veja se pesquisa sobre o que falei aqui da biblioteca.

Qualquer coisa, volta aí que se eu puder ajudar, estarei à disposição.